# gather* and autoaligne errors

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am getting errors with this very simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \autoaligne{%
    a_1+a_2=0\\%
    2a_1-a_2=0%
  }
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The errors are "Missing } inserted." and "Extra }, or forgotten $.". Why are these errors happening?

Also I plan on adding more equations so `gather*` is necessary.

Comment: Why is `gather*` necessary?... If you remove it, you can add different equations as much as you want without any error.

Comment: @Roboticist I found it interesting that I was getting an error. Additionally, it is a bit of a hassle to have to repeatedly type `\[...\]`.

Comment: You don't need to repeatedly type `\[...\]`. Just remove `gather*`, add your equations and consider a break after each one in the `\autoaligne`.

Comment: I filed a bug report.

Comment: The author of `autoaligne` has already answered that a fixed version is on its way to CTAN. `:-D`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

With `autoaligne` version 1.3, released 2017/02/11, the issue has been solved.

---

## Original answer

It's a bug in `autoaligne`, which starts its working with

```
\iffalse{\fi\ifnum`}=0\fi
```

but doesn't add the corresponding code at the end. Indeed, if I add

```
\ifnum`{=0\fi\iffalse}\fi
```

at the end of the code for `\autoaligne_iii`, your code compiles.

Temporary patch, until the package code is fixed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\chardef\saveduscatcode=\catcode`_
\catcode`_=11
\let\saved_autoaligne_iii\autoaligne_iii
\def\autoaligne_iii#1{\saved_autoaligne_iii{#1}\ifnum`{=0\fi\iffalse}\fi}
\catcode`_=\saveduscatcode

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \autoaligne{
    a_1+a_2=0\\
    2a_1-a_2=0
  }
\end{align}

\begin{gather*}
  \autoaligne{
    a_1+a_2=0\\
    2a_1-a_2=0
  }                          
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]